# Video Element Resets on Re-render

Tags: reactjs

I've been playing around with video elements in React. It works fine by using ref's to set the `srcObject`. However, as soon as the application re-renders, the video is lost and it goes black.

Is there anyway to allow the video to keep playing through state updates (re-renders)?

Behaviour of the code below:

1. First call of `getMedia` does nothing.
2. Second call of `getMedia` correctly renders the camera feed in the video element.
3. First call of `startCall` kills the video feed (goes black).

```
export const CallTestingPage: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const localVideoElement = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const remoteVideoElement = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  const [startCallBtnDisabled, setStartCallBtnDisabled] = useState(true);

  async function getMedia() {
    // console.log("getMedia");
    try {
      const cameraStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
      localVideoElement!.current!.srcObject = cameraStream;
      console.log(localVideoElement.current?.srcObject);
      setStartCallBtnDisabled(false);
    } catch (e) {
      const message = `getUserMedia error: ${e.name} :: PermissionDeniedError may mean invalid constraints.`;
      alert(message);
    }
  }

  function startCall() {
    setStartCallBtnDisabled(true);
  }

  function endCall() {}

  function LocalVideo () {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
      <>
        <div id="localVideo">
          <div>LOCAL VIDEO</div>
          <br />
          <video autoPlay muted className={classes.videoPlayer} ref={localVideoElement} />
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
  
  function RemoteVideo () {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
      <>
        <div id="remoteVideo">
          <div>REMOTE VIDEO</div>
          <br />
          <video autoPlay muted className={classes.videoPlayer} ref={remoteVideoElement} />
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <PageSection>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={5}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <LocalVideo />
            </Paper>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              ACTIVE CANDIDATES
              <br />
              <br />
              LOCAL
              <br />
              <br />
              REMOTE
              <br />
            </Paper>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={5}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <RemoteVideo />
            </Paper>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <ButtonGroup color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
              <Button onClick={getMedia}>Get Media</Button>
              <Button onClick={startCall} disabled={startCallBtnDisabled}>Start Call</Button>
              <Button onClick={endCall}>Hang Up</Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
            </Paper>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}> 
              STATS 
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              {/* <div ref={stats}></div> */}
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </PageSection>
  );
}
```

Edit:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(localVideoElement.current?.srcObject)
}, [startCallBtnDisabled])

// this returns null every time
```

Comment: `<video ref={video} />` looks like a typo. Did you try `<video ref={videoElement} />`?

Comment: Ah sorry, I typed this up on my phone. There is no syntax errors. The video does play (such as capturing the camera output), but it stops immediately after a state update.

Comment: Thanks for posting the full/actual code! I think that reveals the issue, while the original code you posted looked fine up to typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the issue is that you've defined function components *inside* another function component.  This is bad practice in general, but particularly problematic in your case because it means, every time the top-level function component re-renders, those components are replaced by brand new component definitions, which means React doesn't know it can re-use existing `<video>` elements.  Try this:

```js
export const CallTestingPage: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const localVideoElement = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const remoteVideoElement = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  const [startCallBtnDisabled, setStartCallBtnDisabled] = useState(true);

  async function getMedia() {
    // console.log("getMedia");
    try {
      const cameraStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
      localVideoElement!.current!.srcObject = cameraStream;
      console.log(localVideoElement.current?.srcObject);
      setStartCallBtnDisabled(false);
    } catch (e) {
      const message = `getUserMedia error: ${e.name} :: PermissionDeniedError may mean invalid constraints.`;
      alert(message);
    }
  }

  function startCall() {
    setStartCallBtnDisabled(true);
  }

  function endCall() {}

  return (
    <PageSection>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={5}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <LocalVideo localVideoElement={localVideoElement} />
            </Paper>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              ACTIVE CANDIDATES
              <br />
              <br />
              LOCAL
              <br />
              <br />
              REMOTE
              <br />
            </Paper>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={5}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <RemoteVideo remoteVideoElement={remoteVideoElement} />
            </Paper>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <ButtonGroup color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
              <Button onClick={getMedia}>Get Media</Button>
              <Button onClick={startCall} disabled={startCallBtnDisabled}>Start Call</Button>
              <Button onClick={endCall}>Hang Up</Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
            </Paper>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}> 
              STATS 
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              {/* <div ref={stats}></div> */}
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </PageSection>
  );
}

function LocalVideo ({localVideoElement}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <div id="localVideo">
        <div>LOCAL VIDEO</div>
        <br />
        <video autoPlay muted className={classes.videoPlayer} ref={localVideoElement} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
  
function RemoteVideo ({remoteVideoElement}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <div id="remoteVideo">
        <div>REMOTE VIDEO</div>
        <br />
        <video autoPlay muted className={classes.videoPlayer} ref={remoteVideoElement} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```